# I have an array but i want to check it separated

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have written an array that gives number from 1 to 100 and after I do push I need to go through the array and get if there is a 2 digit number to separate it and if that separated string is summed(+operation) and gives result 8 to write it

I am using this inside html body tag 
var array = [];

```
function pokreni(){
    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    array.push(i); 
}
}
pokreni();
```

After this, I need to go through my array and if there is number 71, I need it to sum it number by number (7+1) and if the result is 8 to write it in a new array.

Comment: Can you share the expected final output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to quickly separate out those numbers that equal 9.

```js
function pokreni() {
  let array = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
}

let arr = pokreni();

let eights = arr.reduce((p, c) => {
  if (c.toString().split('').reduce((a, b) => +a + +b) === 8) p.push(c);
  return p;
}, []);

console.log(eights)
```

Comment: Thanks that works fine just add value 8 at last line in my case I use document.write("8,"+eights);